# How to choose an axiom system in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle, proof-assistant, isabelle-hol

First of all, sorry if my question is too nonsensical and naive, I'm just getting started with Isabelle/HOL. I am reading Hou's "Fundamentals of Logic and Computation: With Practical Automated Reasoning and Verification". I have the following problems to do using Isabelle/HOL:

> [image]

How do I make Isabelle/HOL prove this assuming only Hilbert's or Lukasiewicz's axiom system? I've done an example in the book but I'm not sure which axioms were used to prove it:

[image]

Comment: It seems that it is part of the prerequisites of the exercise either to implement the different axiom systems or to use only the relevant rules **by hand**. Automated methods will invoke everything they can in order to reach the goal, so they cannot be trusted this kind of work.

Please provide the example in order to get which way things go here.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf How do I do that? BTW: Examples of what? I'm confused.

Comment: If you are getting these instructions from a public source, it would really help to share a link (and chapter/page number if needed).  (I think that is what @PedroSánchezTerraf meant by “example”.)  If these are homework, then it would be good to ask your teacher.  But I think 1.7 and 1.8 likely mean to prove it with pen and paper.  (Although Isabelle is a meta logic so it is possible it instead means to implement that axiom system in Isabelle.  If it means that, then there would likely be an example in the text you referenced of how to do that.)

Comment: Exactly what Jason said (thanks!); I was trying to convey his last sentence.

Comment: I see you included the book title. The chapter is here, but behind a paywall: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-87882-5_1 Given that the footnote to 1.9 tells you where to download Isabelle, and that Isabelle/HOL refers to Isabelle with the HOL axiom-system (the most standard way to use Isabelle), I am even more sure the book is not suggesting you implement Hilbert's or Łukasiewicz's axioms in Isabelle, but just do the problem via pen and paper, and then use Isabelle/HOL's built-in tactics to prove the same result (exactly the sort of thing you are doing in the screenshot).

Comment: @JasonRute No, it's not homework. I'm studying on my own. I asked mentioning the Isabelle/HOL parts. Yeah, I was also thinking that too. I guess I just need to write A->A and A->(¬A -> B) just as I did above but I'd like to learn how to specifically use some axiom system.

Comment: @RedBanana If you want to ask a new specifically about how to implement other logics in Isabelle, I’d upvote it.  (I think this one got interpreted differently so I think a new question is best).

Comment: @JasonRute Yeah, I'm still a bit lost at how to do things but I'm interested in learning.